# Why do I keep getting "expected an indented block" error?

Tags: python, indentation

I have a bunch of if... elif statements iterating in a for loop. I am getting a "expected an indented block" error in the middle of an elif. I can't figure out why.

I am running my code in python 3.7.2 IDLE on Windows. I've looked through other threads, but none of them helped me find the issue.

```py
rows = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]] # rows is a list of 9 lists of nine integers each between 0 and 9 (inclusive)
squares = [] # Where square_interpreter() .append()'s the lists of integers

def square_interpreter(): # Determines the 9 values in each 3 by 3 square in a Sudoku puzzle
    for x in range(9):
        output = []
        if x in [0,1,2]:
            for n in range(3):
                if x == 0:
                    for i in range(3):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 1:
                    for i in range(3,6):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 2:
                    for i in range(6,9):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
        elif x in [3,4,5]:
            for n in range(3,6):
                if x == 3:
                    for i in range(3):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 4:
                    for i in range(3,6):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 5:
                    for i in range(6,9):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
        else:
            for n in range(6,9):
                if x == 6:
                    for i in range(3):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 7:
                    for i in range(3,6):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
                elif x == 8:
                    for i in range(6,9):
                        output.append(rows[n][i])
        squares.append(output)
```

The error occurs on line 12. The message highlights the space between elif and x == 1:

Conclusion of the matter:
I've figured out an entirely different way to do the same thing so that it doesn't give me the error:

```py
def square_interpreter():
    keys_in_square = [[l + n for l in 'ABC' for n in '123'],
                      [l + n for l in 'ABC' for n in '456'],
                      [l + n for l in 'ABC' for n in '789'],
                      [l + n for l in 'DEF' for n in '123'],
                      [l + n for l in 'DEF' for n in '456'],
                      [l + n for l in 'DEF' for n in '789'],
                      [l + n for l in 'GHI' for n in '123'],
                      [l + n for l in 'GHI' for n in '456'],
                      [l + n for l in 'GHI' for n in '789']]
    for index in range(9):
        output = []
        for key in keys_in_square[index]:
            output.append(values[key])
        squares.append(output)
```

I know this looks a lot different and it probably doesn't make any sense without the context, but it does the same thing. It's actually a lot shorter than the old version. Thanks for all your kind help :)

Comment: You might have mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: Is there a way to check if I have?

Comment: Every good IDE or editor would show you. (Yes, there's a hidden message in the sentence.)

Comment: This exact code doesn't appear to mix tabs and spaces, and works for me when I use dummy data for `rows`. Check the line above this code.

Comment: If you copy and paste exactly what you have here back into your project do you get the same error still?

Comment: This code is the first part a function. And yes it is indented correctly.

Comment: @silver it still throws the error code at me

Comment: @Justin is could you give us more context, like values for  `rows` and `output`? or maybe the rest of the function? I can't seem to replicate your issue.

Comment: @silver I updated the question with more context. It is part of a program I am building to solve sudoku puzzles. square_interpreter() is a function that determines which numbers are in each 3 by 3 square of the puzzle using the numbers in each row.

Comment: ```output ``` is just a temporary storage container for a list. It's initialized with an empty list.

Comment: I've just coded the function differently so it doesn't give the error! There are more details at the end of the question. Thanks, for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
for x in range(9):
    output = []
    if x in [0,1,2]:
        for n in range(3):
            if x == 0:
                for i in range(3):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
            elif x == 1:
                for i in range(3,6):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
            elif x == 2:
                for i in range(6,9):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
```

Your issues seems to be on line 2. output = [] is indented a tab too far.

Edit: Apparently not, but either way at least thats fixed now :D

Comment: That wouldn't cause an indent error in my experience.

Comment: Ahh, what IDE do you use by the way? Just curious.

Comment: I use the IDLE (Python 3.7 32-bit) one that installed when i installed python on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

```
rows=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[2,3,2,4,5,3,5,3,2],[2,3,2,4,5,8,9,2,1]]
output = []
for x in range(9):
    if x in [0,1,2]:
        for n in range(3):
            if x == 0:
                for i in range(3):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
            elif x == 1:
                for i in range(3,6):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
            elif x == 2:
                for i in range(6,9):
                    output.append(rows[n][i])
print(output)
```

Above is corrected version of your previously posted code
I am using a dummy rows array
output array should be defined outside the for loop
This does not give any error.
I hope it helps